# how to log "request information" to then send it via email?

Tags: php, logging, phpmailer

I'm trying to create a PHP that can log HTTP information from a request to then send this information via email. I'm trying to send IP, URL referrer, and URL request)

The idea is that `$emailContent` can send:

```
"Someone visited your webpage. IP address:".$remoteIpAddress;
"The referrer URL from the request was:".$urlRefer
"The URL input was: php?".$infoFromUrl
```

$infoFromUrl meant to send url information like log.php?Send-this-info-via-mail

Can anyone help me:

```
<?php

$yourEmailAddress = "user@domain.com";
$emailSubject = "New Visitor on Webpage";
$remoteIpAddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$emailContent = "Someone visited your webpage. IP address:".$remoteIpAddress;

// send the message
mail($yourEmailAddress, $emailSubject, $emailContent);

?>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, what actually you are trying to achieve. Do you want to send log data as email?

Comment: Yes. I want to send the information automatically when the PHP file is call. I was looking into 'HTTP_REFERER'

Comment: You've got some code. Nothing is blindingly obviously wrong with it. What's the problem?

Comment: Not sure how to log the URI like `log.php?Send-this-info-via-mail` I was thinking of using "REQUEST_URI" but I'm not sure if this will work.

Answer (score -1):

The email code you have is very basic, but should work – consider [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) if you want to do a more thorough job.

Logging can be very simple:

```
$msg = "Someone visited your webpage. IP address:" . $remoteIpAddress.
    "The referrer URL from the request was:" . $urlRefer .
    "The URL input was: php?" . $infoFromUrl;
file_put_contents('log.txt', date('Y-m-d H:i:s ').$msg, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Or you can make it more complex by using classes that implement [the PSR-3 standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-3/).